# In Emacs org-mode, how to refile highlighted text under an org heading?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs-helm

In Emacs org-mode, is there a way to automatically refile highlighted text under an org heading? i.e. to cut the highlighted text and automatically paste it under the org-heading of my choice?

You could call it `org-refile-region`. Similar to `org-refile`, but to refile not the entire subtree, but only the highlighted region under any heading in the current document.

UPDATE:

Ideally this functionality would be independent of the org-agenda files used by org-refile, so as to avoid displaying irrelevant headings as possible targets.

Currently this is doable by doing:
1. select text
2. cut
3. other-window
4. navigate to desired target heading
5. paste text
6. other window

The proposed new function would make this much more efficient:
1. select text
2. org-refile-region
3. choose target

The most useful form of this would allow you to choose a target from among any currently open documents. My use case involves selecting text from one buffer and refiling it from among org-headings in another buffer, i.e. moving text from a source document displayed in one window and refiling to targets within the hierarchy of a target document displayed in another window, like so:

[image]

Comment: Are you using something like `*word*` to highlight text, or are you using another means?  If other, please specify how you achieve the highlighting that relates to your question.

Comment: Shift-select, i.e. S-<right> and S-<left>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using emacs 24.1 or later, you can try

```
(setq org-refile-active-region-within-subtree t)
```

which will almost do what you want, but turn the line in which you have highlighted text (the emacs term is "active region") into a headline.

If you want to move the text you have highlighted to another heading, you have to extend org-mode. Fortunately, org provides the tools you need. Here is an example:

```
(defvar org-refile-region-format "\n%s\n")

(defvar org-refile-region-position 'top
  "Where to refile a region. Use 'bottom to refile at the
end of the subtree. ")

(defun org-refile-region (beg end copy)
  "Refile the active region.
If no region is active, refile the current paragraph.
With prefix arg C-u, copy region instad of killing it."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  ;; mark paragraph if no region is set
  (unless (use-region-p)
    (setq beg (save-excursion
                (backward-paragraph)
                (skip-chars-forward "\n\t ")
                (point))
          end (save-excursion
                (forward-paragraph)
                (skip-chars-backward "\n\t ")
                (point))))
  (let* ((target (save-excursion (org-refile-get-location)))
         (file (nth 1 target))
         (pos (nth 3 target))
         (text (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (unless copy (kill-region beg end))
    (deactivate-mark)
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char pos)
        (if (eql org-refile-region-position 'bottom)
            (org-end-of-subtree)
          (org-end-of-meta-data-and-drawers))
        (insert (format org-refile-region-format text))))))
```

We use `org-refile-get-location` to apply the org refiling mechanism and extract the file and the location. Then we go to that location and insert the copied text. Two variables added for convenience.

`org-refile-targets` lets you control which files to consider, e.g.:

```
nil  ;; only the current file
'((org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 2)) ;; all agenda files, 1st/2nd level
'((org-files-list :maxlevel . 4)) ;; all agenda and all open files
'((my-org-files-list :maxlevel . 4)) ;; all files returned by `my-org-files-list'
```

To restrict refiling to the currently open org buffers, define a function

```
(defun my-org-files-list ()
  (mapcar (lambda (buffer)
            (buffer-file-name buffer))
          (org-buffer-list 'files t)))
```

And then either

```
(setq org-refile-targets '((my-org-files-list :maxlevel . 4)))
```

or use

```
M-x customize-option <ret> org-refile-targets
```

select "Function" from the "value menu", and type `my-org-files-list`

Comment: Great! Is there any way to make it offer me headings in the current document only?

Comment: Yes. The possible targets are selected according to `org-refile-targets`. If this variable is `nil` (which it is by default), only the current buffer is considered. I've modified my example, because you specifically asked for "any heading in the current document."

Comment: What about drawing from any open file? I added an update to explain what I mean.

Comment: Yes, this can be done as well. See `org-refile-targets`.

Comment: Is there a way to set `org-refile-targets` to consider not just the current buffer, but all currently open buffers?

Comment: I have updated my answer. `org-refile-region` now uses `org-refile-targets` plus I added instructions on how to customize the latter.

Comment: And yes, this only works for org buffers. You cannot refile to buffers that are not in org mode.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting `bad refiling target description (:max-level . 4)`.

Comment: The keyword is called :maxlevel, not :max-level. Sorry about the typo.

Comment: That works perfectly! Is there a way to direct the function to use the `ido` interface (good) or the `helm` interface (even better) for the choice of headings?

Comment: It appears the function `org-refile-region` defined above no longer works as of org-mode version 9.2. Rather than refiling the highlighted region of text to the target heading I select, org simply places it at the bottom of the file. Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: @incandescentman Replace `org-end-of-meta-data-and-drawers` with `org-end-of-meta-data t`